# How do I put a product in a category using spinner dropdown?

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSaUC.png)I wanted to add a function to my spinner
I want to ADD a PRODUCT in my Food TABLE,  I input a name of product "ADOBO" and I input a PRICE "50" and I want to put a "ADOBO" in FOOD CATEGORY and there's two item in my spinner, Category food and Category drinks. How do I put my Product in FOOD TABLE using Spinner

```
    //SPINNER DROPDOWN
    List<String> List = new ArrayList<>();
    List.add("Food");
    List.add("Drinks");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, List);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerCT.setAdapter(adapter);

}


public void Addproduct(){
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String name = NameOfProduct.getText().toString().trim();
            String price = PriceOfProduct.getText().toString().trim();


            spinnerCT.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String itemvalue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Not clear about your requirements, please make it clear

Comment: I put image now, I hope it help you understand my Problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove Spinner `onItemSelectedListener` from `onClick`

And inside onClick use:

```
spinnerCT.getSelectedItem()
```

It gives you the category

And if you need to set the `onItemSelectedListener`, please set it in `onCreate` after setting adapter.